# IIS 8.5 FTP using IIS Users

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, asp.net

Can someone please provide me with an up-to-date step-by-step guide on how to add ftp publishing securely using SSL to a website in IIS 8.5 web server using IIS Users.

I then want to connect to the website using FileZilla.

1. I have correctly installed ftp using windows firewall. All rules are enabled.
2. I have installed IIS Service Management and have created an IIS user (IISuser with a password).
3. I have tried selecting my site and creating an ftp publishing but every time I try to connect to the server with the IIS User through FileZilla after authenticating the SSL by trusting it in FileZilla I get a 503 invalid host name.

I want to create an IIS user to access the ftp, instead of a user on the server because I want to ensure maximum amount of security - if I create another user with limited access, they can still remote into the server, rather than just an IIS user being able to access the web server (IIS).

Comment: so your problem is not with the IIS user, but the general connection to the server? Does it work when using a Windows account?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf it doesn't seem to work with a user account either. I am baffled. I have re-installed the ftp ports via server manager and restarted the server. I must be mucking something up when I set up the main server ftp configuration in IIS and then again at the site level. Any tips/guidance?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like an admin account can connect to the FTP but not an IIS user. Any help with this?